# want to cmp pot and mot array with string array and insert missing value into new array

Tags: java, arrays

```
 import java.io.*;

 import java.util.*


 class assmm 
{

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
{

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9;

    /*s1=new String("JOHN START 0");
    s2=new String("USING *,15");
    s3=new String("L 1,FIVE");
    s4=new String("A 1,FOUR");
    s5=new String("ST 1,TEMP");
    s6=new String("FOUR DC F,4");
    s7=new String("FIVE DC F,15");
    s8=new String("TEMP DS 1F");
    s9=new String("END");   
    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(s2);
    System.out.println(s3);
    System.out.println(s4);
    System.out.println(s5);
    System.out.println(s6);
    System.out.println(s7);
    System.out.println(s8);
    System.out.println(s9);*/


    String mot[][]=new String[4][2];
    mot[0][0]="mot table";
    mot[1][0]="L";
    mot[1][1]="4";
    mot[2][0]="A";
    mot[2][1]="4";
    mot[3][0]="ST";
    mot[3][1]="4";
    for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=1;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(mot[i][j]);
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    String pot[]=new String[6];
    pot[0]="pot";
    pot[1]="Start";
    pot[2]="Using";
    pot[3]="DC";
    pot[4]="DS";
    pot[5]="END";
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(pot[i]);
    }

            /*System.out.println("PROGRAM");
        String pgm[]=new String[9];
            pgm[0]="JOHN START 0";
            pgm[1]="USING *,15";
            pgm[2]="L 1,FIVE";
            pgm[3]="A 1,FOUR";
            pgm[4]="ST 1,TEMP";
            pgm[5]="FOUR DC F,4";
            pgm[6]="FIVE DC F,15";
            pgm[7]="TEMP DS 1F";
            pgm[8]="END";*/
            String str[]={"JOHN","START","0","spr","USING","*",",","15","spr","L","1",",","FIVE","spr","A","1",",","FOUR","spr","ST","1",",","TEMP","spr","FOUR","DC","F","'4'","spr","FIVE","DC","F","'5'","spr","TEMP","DS","'1'","F","spr","END"};
    int len=str.length;
    System.out.println(len);
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                    for(int j=0;j<=(mot.length)-1;j++)
                    {
                            if(str[i]==mot[j][0])
                            {
                                    System.out.println(str[i]+"found in mot");
                             }
                     }
                    for(int j=0;j<=(pot.length)-1;j++)
                    {
                            if(str[i]==pot[j])
                            {
                                    System.out.println(str[i]+"found in pot");
                             }                 
                     }

            }                 


            /*for(int i=0;i<pgm.length;i++)
            {
                    System.out.println(pgm[i]);
             }*/
            /*int len=pgm.length
             for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
             {
                    for(int j=0;j<=(mot.length)-1;j++)
                    {
                              if(pgm[i]==mot[j][0])
                              {
                                    System.out.println(pgm[i]+"found in mot");
                              }
                    }
            }*/

     }
```

}

want to cmp pot and mot array with string array and insert missing value into new array....

just repeated text.... ignore below
want to cmp pot and mot array with string array and insert missing value into new array
want to cmp pot and mot array with string array and insert missing value into new array

Comment: So what problem are you having with what you have written so far?

Comment: not able to compare the pot and mot array with the string array

Comment: ah right, that's made it a lot clearer.